# using memset and freeaddrinfo causes the double free or corruption error

Tags: c++, sockets, memory, memset

src.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(){
  
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    getaddrinfo(NULL, "1560", &hints, &servinfo);
    freeaddrinfo(&hints);


}
```

I used gdb to find out where the error occurs and it occurs at the memset
but when I comment out the call to freeaddrinfo(), it gives no error and works!

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.2 kernel 5.8.0-55-generic

edit:
as you pointed out that I should give freeaddrinfo a list provided by getaddrinfo, when I pass servinfo to freeaddrinfo, it gives the following error

```
double free or corruption (out)
[1]    4123 abort (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

edit 2: thanks, when editing the question I forgot to replace the &hints with servinfo, and thought that I had already replaced it, sorry for the inconvinience, I deserve every bit of downvote for my stupidity.

Comment: You could try using [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> freeaddrinfo(&hints);
> ```

This is expected behaviour (in the way that it the behaviour is undefined; not in the way that you could rely on this behaviour). You may only pass structure created by `getaddrinfo` into `freeaddrinfo`. You didn't create `&hints` with `getaddrinfo`. Don't pass `hints` into `freeaddrinfo`.

A fixed example:

```
addrinfo hints {
    .ai_flags    = AI_PASSIVE,
    .ai_family   = AF_UNSPEC,
    .ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM,
};
addrinfo* result;
int err = getaddrinfo(nullptr, "12345", &hints, &result);
if (err) {
    std::cout << "getaddrinfo: " << gai_strerror(err);
    std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
} else {
    // use it here

    freeaddrinfo(result); // pay particular attention to this
}
```

> I replaced it with freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

Your new example still has `freeaddrinfo(&hints)` but also `freeaddrinfo(servinfo)`. If you replace the former with the latter, then you're calling `freeaddrinfo(servinfo)` twice. You may not use the invalidated `servinfo` after you've freed it, including passing it into `freeaddrinfo` a second time. Similar rules apply as would apply to `std::free`.

Comment: as you pointed out that I should give freeaddrinfo a list provided by getaddrinfo, when I pass servinfo to freeaddrinfo, it gives double free or corruption error :(

Comment: @HPSmash77 You must remove the line `freeaddrinfo(&hints);`

Comment: I replaced it with freeaddrinfo(servinfo); and then it gives the error I specivied in the previous comment

Comment: @HPSmash77 See edit. Also see my example.

Comment: oh! sorry, forgot to do that when editing the code :(

Answer (score 3):

The [`freeaddrinfo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/freeaddrinfo.html) function expects a pointer to a list of `addrinfo` structures created by [`getaddrinfo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/freeaddrinfo.html).

The pointer you pass is not to such a list of structures, so that will lead to *undefined behavior* inside the function

---

The `getaddrinfo` function very likely allocates the structures using `malloc`, and the `freeaddr` function passes them to `free`.

You can't pass a pointer to `free` that wasn't returned by `malloc` (or other related function like `calloc` or `realloc`).

---

You don't dynamically allocate space for `hints`. You allocate it on the stack. It should not be passed to `freeaddrinfo`, only the result (`servinfo` in your case) should be.

Comment: as you pointed out that I should give freeaddrinfo a list provided by getaddrinfo, when I pass servinfo to freeaddrinfo, it gives double free or corruption error :(

Comment: @HPSmash77 Just don't call `freeaddrinfo(&hints)`? As a general hint: Whenever you need to use the pointer-to (or address-of) operator `&` when calling any function containing the term `free`, you should take that as a sign you're doing something wrong.